# TCPDF: 2 lines are overlapping to each other and Y is not working

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf to write down a pdf from html. All the content are smooth and writing properly but end of the page I am writing the username and below it adjusting it's signature. Despite of trying lot of method second line is not printing to the next line and it's overlapping to the first one.

```
$pdf->resetLastH();
$x1 = 15;
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,$x1,$Y,"User Name: ",array(),0,false,false,'L',true);
$Y = $pdf->GetY();
$fname_sign = !empty($_SESSION['firstname']) ? $_SESSION['firstname'] : "";
$lname_sign = !empty($_SESSION['lastname']) ? $_SESSION['lastname'] : "";
$fullName   = $fname_sign." ". $lname_sign;
$x1 = $x1+$pdf->GetStringWidth("Patient Name: ")+5; 
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,$x1,$Y,$fullName,array(),0,false,false,'L',true);

$Y = $pdf->GetY();
$x1 = $x1+75;
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,$x1,$Y,"Date: ",array(),0,false,false,'L',true);
$Y = $pdf->GetY();
$x1 = $x1+$pdf->GetStringWidth("Date: ")+5;
$now = date("Y-m-d");
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,$x1+15,$Y,$now,array(),0,false,false,'L',true);

$x1 = 15;
$Y = $pdf->GetY()+$pdf->getLastH()+15;
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,$x1,$Y,"User Signature: ",array(),0,false,false,'L',true);
$x1 = $x1+$pdf->GetStringWidth("User Signature: ")+5;
$Y = $pdf->GetY()-10;
$pdf->Image($sign_img,$x1,$Y,50,20,"png",'','',true,320);
```

If I am commenting last line then things are good but it's overlapping to first line if uncomment.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use that if I were you, I think `Dompdf` is a better approach. check it out!
https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/convert-html-to-pdf-in-php-with-dompdf-example